# Android Studio instant run doesnt work

Tags: android, android-studio

Since I installed 2.0 beta 4, it has been really bad (same with 2.1 preview).
**When I do instant run it doesn't apply ANY changes**. Sometimes some XML changes works, but not Java.

It has been working good on 2.0 beta 2, but beta 2 is doesn't working anymore.

I always need to manually uninstall app. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Along with updating your Android Studio, keep updating your Gradle plugin version for instant run support.

Eg: For Android Studio 2.1 Preview 3, your gradle plugin version should be
2.1.0-alpha3.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: Instant run is still in its early stages. Instant run currently works for almost all xml specific changes. For java changes, it does work but not for all.

Also some instant swapping requires API 21+.  Have a look at this link : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run